# Passing parameter from Java to Python and vise versa

Tags: java, python, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a python code that waits for input parameter. This input is the output of another java code. Is there any way I can pass the parameters between the two codes like a bridge between the two?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so...where's your code？

Comment: You could write the output of the Java program to stdout and in the python program read from stdin. Or just use TCP sockets.

Comment: use a tcp ip communication, define the java as server and the python as client... connect them and transfer data

Comment: writing to a file was not that successful as I have many threads writing to the same file, So I'll try the TCP communication.. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do these kind of tasks is to use a message broker like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). It provides support for Java, Python, PHP, etc. You can send messages (a json message for example, or in any other format) between processes implemented with different languages. [Here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) you can find tutorials implemented with different languages.

**RabitMQ**
RabbitMQ is a message broker. It sits between producers and consumers. Producers are components which produces messages and publish those messages to a queue in the RabbitMQ. RabbitMQ takes those messages and by the rules you defined routes and delivers those messages to the consumers. Consumers are task runners which wait to receive messages and run tasks. Here is a simple producer which connects to RabbitMQ, sends a single message, and exit.

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;

public class Send {
  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws java.io.IOException {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    String message = "Hello World!";
    channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
    System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    channel.close();
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

And here we have a simple java consumer which we keep it running to listen for messages. You are not limited to java. You can use any language which there are RabbitMQ libraries for (Python, PHP, C#, JavaScript, etc):

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Recv {

  private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "hello";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
      @Override
      public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
          throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
      }
    };
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
  }
}
```

To run it:

```
$ javac -cp rabbitmq-client.jar Send.java Recv.java
$ java -cp .:commons-io-1.2.jar:commons-cli-1.1.jar:rabbitmq-client.jar Send
$ java -cp .:commons-io-1.2.jar:commons-cli-1.1.jar:rabbitmq-client.jar Recv
```

Note: you'll need `rabbitmq-client.jar` and its dependencies on the classpath.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11747108)

Comment: @RoadieRich Thanks, I updated my question

Comment: I think you have the producer and consumer reversed from what the original question is about.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of process interconnection have two main problems: serialization and transport.

When you passing data from Java process to Python application most likely you want to see a object of specific type rather than raw-bytes or text. There is number of frameworks that was designed to handle cross-language behavior. Take a look at [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/), [Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf) or [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/). Each one have it's own [pros and cons](http://www.slideshare.net/IgorAnishchenko/pb-vs-thrift-vs-avro).

Second problem is transport. Like @Mustafa Shujaie already said message-oriented transport like RabitMQ is a good choice. But also have a look at  REST services for [Java](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and [Python](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask).

By the way, if you take byte-oriented serialization like Protobuf then plain TCP transport could be a good choice - data overhead would be significantly lover in comparison to any application-leveled protocol like HTTP. See this articles: [python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) and [java](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed both programs on a single device you can consider using libraries that supports handling interprocess communication (IPC) such as [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/).

It has bindings for both:

- [Java bindings](http://zeromq.org/bindings:java)
- [Python bindings](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python)

I've successfully applied communication with 0MQ on embedded system with ARM processors. It acs as a communication bus between programs written in multiple languages (mostly in C and Python in my case).

While prototyping you can use human readable data format (like JSON). There were a lot of libraries that supports (de)serializing JSONs in Java (like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)). Python has native modules for that.